# How can I put RSpec Rails Controller tests in a different directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I'd like to put a few integration tests in a separate directory from my controller unit specs. However, when I move my spec file to spec/integration, it fails with:

```
ArgumentError:
       bad argument(expected URI object or URI string)
```

The spec passes correctly when in the spec/controllers directory.

Here's a bit from my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Users::LoginsController, type: :controller do
  let!(:user) { User.create(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test')

  it 'logs in the user' do
    post :create, email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test'
    controller.current_user.should == user
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.3, RSpec 2.7.0.

Are there any tricks I have to use to achieve this?

Comment: Forgot to copy that in, fixed the post.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying type:

```
describe ProductsController, type: :controller do
  it 'can test #show' do
    get :show
  end
end
```

Works in Rails 3.2.11

Comment: It also works in Rails 2.3.18 and RSpec 1.3.2, but using this syntax:  
`describe ProductsController, :type => :controller do`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:

```
describe Users::LoginsController do
  controller_name 'users/logins'

  ... the rest of your spec here ...

end
```

I am not entirely certain about the nested syntax, but at least you need to specify the `controller_name` to get it to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like the right idea, but it looks like that method has been deprecated. :(

Answer (score 0):

The test framework does not like it if you specify the test action using a symbol.

```
it 'logs in the user' do
    post :create, email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test'
    controller.current_user.should == user
end
```

becomes

```
it 'logs in the user' do
    post 'create', email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test'
    controller.current_user.should == user
end
```

Comment: FWIW I couldn't get RSpec 2 to work with controllers in different directories.  I think the correct way to do it is use tagging - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/command-line/tag-option

Comment: I tag at the describe level - "describe FooController, mode: integration do" - and then rspec --tags mode:integration / ~mode:integration.  There is no correct value, it's arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for me in Rails 4 and RSpec 2.14.7:

My findings:

1. Don't name your directory `integration`. I need to grep through the source of either RSpec or Rails, but it appears to have an adverse effect on running controller specs.  Perhaps someone with this knowledge can chime in to confirm this.
2. Name it something other than integration; in my case I tried `int`, which resulted in problems *until* I added the "type: :controller" after the `#describe` method.
3. After that, I was able to move all of my slow Rails specs into my `int` directory, allowing me to create a `unit` directory for all of my decoupled, fast specs.

Please let me know if this works for you.

By the way, I am running:

1. Ruby 1.9.3
2. Rails 4.0.2
3. rspec-core 2.14.7
4. rspec-rails 2.14.1

all on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up simply using the URL

`get "/users"`

It's not as clean but gets the job done. I couldn't get the other suggestions to work.

Answer (score -9):

Take the opportunity now to get rid of your controller and integration specs. They're needlessly painful to write and too coupled to implementation. Replace them with Cucumber stories. Your life will be much easier...

Comment: I'm actually not that fond of Cucumber. I can't any reason why I shouldn't be able to do this. And testing the integration between controllers and models seems worthwhile to me.

Comment: It is worthwhile to do that -- but RSpec is the wrong tool. Learn to use Cucumber rather than disliking it.

Comment: Doesn't help to answer the question and too opinionated in my view. Cucumber is not the only tool on the market ...

Comment: No, but it's the best for this case. I've tried the others; nothing is as good. RSpec controller tests focus on the wrong things. Am I opinionated? Absolutely. So is Rails. So is RSpec.

Comment: Just saying that your statement might be helpful as a comment aka "Check this out - helped me a lot". But it does not qualify as an answer since it does not address the inital problem @Ben mentioned. Is he supposed to adjust hundreds of existing tests only to workaround his problem? There must be an easier solution ...

Comment: Have you ever managed a project with multiple developers with cucumber? Shared regex namespaces are a nightmare with large projects, and coupling that with shared modules just confuses it even more.

Comment: @Nthalk I've worked on many multi-developer projects with Cucumber. Shared regex namespaces work pretty well if you write your steps and features correctly, and I have no idea what you're talking about with shared modules.